# How to find current record's RecordType name

Tags: apex, trigger, record-type

I have a requirement where I have to write some logic in an `Opportunity` Trigger.

Requiremnt is , I have find out current `opportunity's` record type and have to check whether that recordtype name contains some value or not.

Is there any way to find out the current `opportunity` record's Recordtype Name ?

I found 1 useful link:
https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_class_Schema_RecordTypeInfo.htm

But,  confused how to use that in my logic.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you are doing this in the trigger it would be something like this:

```
trigger OnOpportunity on Opportunity(before update){

     Map<ID,Schema.RecordTypeInfo> rt_Map = Opportunity.sObjectType.getDescribe().getRecordTypeInfosById();

     for(Opportunity opp : trigger.new){

          if(rt_map.get(opp.recordTypeID).getName().containsIgnoreCase('YOUR VALUE')){
               //Do your stuff
          }

     }


}
```

Comment: Your code works pretty well.But like suppose is it works like in one record type some custom picklist is there.Whenever user selects value in that picklist. it's automatically saved to standard object field @Eric

Answer (score 8):

If you have a deep stack of dependent triggers (and some Orgs do) you can save yourself a SOQL by adding a formula field to the opportunity object, with a return type of Text, and a value of

```
RecordType.Name
```

If for example the formula field is called RecordTypeName you can access it directly in the trigger without querying again.

```
for(Opportunity opp : trigger.new){
    if(opp.RecordTypeName.containsIgnoreCase('YOUR VALUE')){
        //Do your stuff
    }
}
```

If you don't want to go as far as adding a formula to the object, you can still save the SOQL by using the RecordTypeInfos instead of a SOQL query to get your map:

```
map<Id, Schema.RecordTypeInfo> rt_map = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('Opportunity').getDescribe().getRecordTypeInfosById()
for(Opportunity opp : trigger.new){
    if(rt_map.get(opp.recordTypeID).getName().containsIgnoreCase('YOUR VALUE')){
        //Do your stuff
    }
 }
```

See https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_class_Schema_RecordTypeInfo.htm

Comment: With describe limits removed this option is my preference

Comment: I think it should be opp.RecordType.Name.containsIgnoreCase('YOUR VALUE'). Note the dot operator after RecordType.