# Opportunity Validation to exclude certain Profile types

Tags: trigger, validation

Unfortunately, I'm not able to use simple Validation Rules to do my conditional statement validation. Instead I have to use a trigger to do so.

That being said, currently, I'm trying to only run this trigger on certain profile types. We have different records for our Opportunities and I only want it to run on, for example 'SGIOpportunities'. Here is the current code I have:

```
trigger UpdateOpportunity on Opportunity (before insert, before update){    

    Set<String> recordTypeToValidateAgainst = new Set<String>();
    recordTypeToValidateAgainst.add('SGIOpportunities'); // SGI Opportunity Type

    for(Opportunity opp: trigger.new){
        if(recordTypeToValidateAgainst.contains(Schema.RecordTypeInfo.getName()) && opp.StageName != '0 %'){
            OpportunityMethods.updateOppCompetitor(opp);  
        }
    }  
}
```

**`OpportunityMethods.updateOppCompetitor(opp)` is declared in an APEX class, that are my conditional statements.

Also the error I'm getting in the compiler is:

> Error: Compile Error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature:
>   Schema.RecordTypeInfo.getName() at line 7 column 49

Note: I do have the fully qualified name: Schema.RecordTypeInfo.getName() listed and not sure why it's not able to get the value..

Thanks for you help in advance!

Comment: what is the actual need for the trigger? Why can't you use a validation rule?

Comment: I'm trying to dynamically update a multi-select picklist which you can't do with Validation Rules on certain conditions.

Comment: are you trying to see if the recordtype of the opportunity record being saved / edited matches against a specific record type 'SGIOpportunities'?

Comment: Yes, the 'record type name' is 'SGIOpportunities'. Just to reiterate I only want the trigger to perform on recordtype = 'SGIOpportunities'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I rephrased the answer from this SFSE post to accommodate your need :

[How to find current record's RecordType name](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/45847/how-to-find-current-records-recordtype-name)

```
trigger UpdateOpportunity on Opportunity (before insert, before update){    

    Set<String> recordTypeToValidateAgainst = new Set<String>();
    recordTypeToValidateAgainst.add('SGIOpportunities'); // SGI Opportunity Type

map<Id, Schema.RecordTypeInfo> rt_map = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('Opportunity').getDescribe().getRecordTypeInfosById();


    for(Opportunity opp: trigger.new){
        if(recordTypeToValidateAgainst.contains(rt_map.get(opp.recordTypeID).getName()) && opp.StageName != '0 %'){
            OpportunityMethods.updateOppCompetitor(opp);  
        }
    }  
}
```

OR

This should work too:

```
    trigger UpdateOpportunity on Opportunity (before insert, before update){    

    map<Id, Schema.RecordTypeInfo> rt_map = Schema.getGlobalDescribe()get('Opportunity').getDescribe().getRecordTypeInfosById()
    for(Opportunity opp : trigger.new){
        if(rt_map.get(opp.recordTypeID).getName().containsIgnoreCase('SGIOpportunities') && opp.StageName != '0 %'){
              OpportunityMethods.updateOppCompetitor(opp);  
        }
}     
}
```

**Update**: Missed a . here 
Was:

getGlobalDescribe()get('Opportunity')

updated to:

getGlobalDescribe().get('Opportunity')

Comment: Thanks rao. My compiler is looking for a semi-colon for the get statement. Please see error below:  Error: Compile Error: expecting a semi-colon, found 'get' at line 3 column 65                I even added a semi-colon at the end of getRecordTypeInfosById()

Comment: @user3708392 updated the ans

Comment: Hi rao, your solution is not working, and my admin is saying that I'm making the trigger to complex for what I'm trying to do. He recommended the following trigger:    trigger UpdateOpportunity on Opportunity (before insert, before update){    
    for(Opportunity opp : trigger.new){
        if(opp.RecordType.Name == 'SGI Opportunity' && opp.StageName != 'Lead 0 %'){
            OpportunityMethods.updateOppCompetitor(opp);  
        }
    }     
}
But that doesn't work either. All I'm really trying to check is if Record Type Name = SGIOpportunity, if so perform the logic.

Comment: @user3708392 your trigger will work if you change for(opportuntiy opp: trigger.new){} to for(opportuntiy opp: [ select id, recordtype.name, stagename from opportunity where id in:trigger.new]){} you can access recordtypeid without querying for recordtype from trigger.new, but not the name or other recordtype related columns.

Comment: Sweet thanks so much for your input and help. (Hopefully) One last question, I think your where clause has an error in it. 'where id in:trigger.new' not sure but that doesn't look right. Also, in my compiler it doesn't like Opportunity in the From statement. See Error: Compile Error: unexpected token: 'Opportunity' at line 2 column 59

Comment: it should be trigger.new() , sorry have been replying from my phone so lazy typing ()

Comment: What does 'where id in' mean though

Comment: Trigger.new() returns a list of sobjects, in our trigger context a list of opportunities.- https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_triggers_context_variables.htm You are iterating on a list of opportunities and selecting recordtype name from the list of opportunities.